# Is this appropriate for codereview.SE?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, specific-question

I had some confusions about a particular piece of code that I wrote: [Thoughts on refactoring a generic DAO](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219960/thoughts-on-refactoring-a-generic-dao). I placed it on programmers.SE when I thought it was just a design thing. Now I am thinking that it may need a code review also. So I want to know: is such a question appropriate for the site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is such a question appropriate for the site?

#### Yup.

Though your CR post should include more of the code<sup>1</sup>, **not just a high-level overview**. And since you know you're **solving a solved problem** and don't want to be bothered with ORM alternatives you could also tag it with [reinventing-the-wheel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel), which is meant for that, and the [refactoring](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/refactoring) tag looks like it was created for this question :)

<sup>1</sup> If it's *a lot* of code, you may consider breaking it down into several, more digestible posts.

Comment: Actually confused about how much should be placed for review. Is 500-600 lines of code considered a lot of code? Or should I upload it on github and link it?

Comment: @AseemBansal We like our posts self-contained, github+link is nice as an *extra*, but *only* github+link will get your question closed (all code to be reviewed must be in the question). I think it mostly depends on the scope of your code - if it's well-written cohesive code, 500-600 lines might read like a novel. If it's a spaghetti nightmare, best split it into multiple posts; in all cases, break your code blocks to ease reading, use formatting, subtitles, etc., and ask yourself: *"would I want to review this code, as posted?"*

Comment: I know about the rule of self-contained but it is my first time posting such a big code so just wanted to clear things about that. The code is well-written, at least as far as I know. If 500-600 lines are not a big deal then I'll post it all with a github link.

Comment: Added the question. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36519/generic-dao-written-in-java

Comment: @AseemBansal just saw your original post mentioned in the Programmers newsletter :)

Comment: @Where is this newsletter?

Comment: @AseemBansal Click that "Preferences" link in your user profile :)

Comment: So we can subscribe to the newsletters? I didn't know that. What was the mention about? Anything particular?

Comment: @AseemBansal it was under the **Can you answer these?** section, so your post might have gotten a couple more eyes on recently :)